# What is Correct Way to implement a EJB to search using form parameters?

Tags: jpa, ejb

I have this Bean that works.  I would like to implement a method in order to receive parameters from a JSF search form, perform the search and return the results.

So, my questions are:
- What would be a method signature to Wrap my search parameters?
- Is there a way to config the Hibernate/JPA behavior to make a single SELECT that returns all registries that fits my search parameter instead of my actual behavior (1 query excuted per row returned)?

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import my.package.entity.Address;

@Stateful
public class AddressEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "RentACar-persistence-unit",type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Address> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Address> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(
                "Address.findAll", Address.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
  /*This is the method I want to write*/
    public List<Address> findByParameter() {
        TypedQuery<Address> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(
                "Address.findAll", Address.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }   

    public Address addNew(Address address) {
        entityManager.persist(address);
        return address;
    }

    public Address update(Address address) {
        entityManager.merge(address);
        return address;
    }

    public void delete(Address country) {
        entityManager.remove(country);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Query itself varies according to parameters so is the method. You can overload the method with different parameters but there seems nothing plausible to have only a single method. (The method may have optional parameters but that will enforce additional checks in the method body (logic)).

Comment: @Tiny Assuming my form has 3 fields if I follow the idea of a method overloaded I would need 8 methods.  So, the alternative is to wrap the form and work with logic implementation.

Comment: So, my first question is ok...What about the second?

Is there a way to config the Hibernate/JPA behavior to make a single SELECT that returns all registries that fits my search parameter instead of my actual behavior (1 query excuted per row returned)?

Comment: Collect parameters in a key/value pair mechanism like a `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`, if order is significant, pass that `Map` as a method parameter and use the JPA criteria API based on conditional predicates and/or expressions  to generate a query dynamically (true the code will look somewhat ugly but it has to be done, when a query is to be generated / produced dynamically).